# How to pss a ObjectMessage from perl to JMS

Tags: message, transformation, stomp

I want to send a perl object as a message to JMS server. I am using Net::Stomp to send a message from perl client to jms server. I am able to send text message but i want to construct a object similar to java object and send it to jms and convert that perl object back to java object at jms server. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Message Transformation section of the ActiveMQ [Stomp support page](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) it shows how an XML object (also works with JSON) can be sent to the ActiveMQ broker and converted into a Java object.  You can also register and create your own Transformation class as well if you don't want to use XML or JSON.